# The asin() function from cmath library returns inaccurate values

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, trigonometry, cmath

I'm using the *asin* and *acos* functions from *cmath* library to find the angles from their corresponding *sine* and *cosine* values but it sometimes returns inaccurate values. For example the result of the code below is not zero:

```
cout << acos(-1) / 6 - asin(0.5) << endl;
```

So what can I do? I use *acos(-1)* as the value of Pi, then somewhere in my code I want to see for example how many *asin(0.5)* are there in Pi but current method doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The context is the same, but I posted this mostly because of the solution. I have tried the solutions in that post, e.g., rounding but they didn't work as I expected. My code had to pass several tests and just the method I mentioned below worked in all the tests, using other solutions my code wasn't able to pass all the tests.

Comment: AK 12, "the result of the code below is not zero" --> what was the result you saw?

Comment: AK 12, "but current method doesn't work" --> If you need help with the method, post the code.

Comment: There's an example of how to implement an `almost_equal` function here: [std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Inexactness lurks in various places.

`double` is very commonly encoded using base 2, such as with [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  As a  floating point number, it can be expected to be a [Dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).  The key is that a finite floating-point number is a *rational number*.

Mathematically, arccos(-1) is π.  π is an *irrational number*.  Even with many digits of precision, a `double` **cannot represent *exactly* π**.  Instead a nearby value for `acos(-1)` is used called machine pi or perhaps `M_PI`.

Mathematically, arcsin(0.5) is π/6.  As above, `asin(0.5)` is a nearby value to π/6.

Division by 3 introduces potential inexactness.  About 2 of every `double/3` results in an inexact, yet rounded, quotient.

- Of course it is not zero.

What is curious about this is that `acos(-1) / 3 - asin(0.5)` is about 1.57..., not 0.0.

I suspect OP was researching `acos(-1) / 6 - asin(0.5)`.

Here subtraction of nearby values incurs [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) and a small, but non-zero difference, is a likely outcome.

---

> So what can I do?
>   I want to see for example how many asin(0.5) are there in Pi

Tolerate marginal error in the calculation and employ the desired rounding.

```
double my_pi = acos(-1);
double target = asin(0.5);
long close_integer_quotient = lround(my_pi/target);
```